# using getPixel() method and then checking rgb values

Tags: android, colors

I'm using the getPixel() method to return the rgb value of each pixel in a bitmap. Then I use if() statements to compare the rgb values to my own predefined rgb values and then execute code if the statement is true. As seen below:

```
for(int x=startX; x<w; x++){
            for(int y=startY; y<h; y++){
                int pixel = img.getPixel(x, y);

                if(pixel == Color.rgb(255, 255, 255)); //some code
                if(pixel == Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)); //some code
                if(pixel == Color.rgb(255, 255, 0)); //some code
                if(pixel == Color.rgb(120, 60, 0)); //some code
}
```

My issue is that while the first three if() statements get executed, the fourth one never does. I know my image contains pixels with all those rgb values because I made the image myself. I'm guessing the problem is because there's no predefined variable in the color class with an rgb value of (120,60,0). So basically I'm wondering if there's anyway around this issue. Maybe a better method than getPixel()? I just need the code in the fourth if() statement to be able to execute.

EDIT- more info:

My image has a png extension. I load it to a bitmap in the following way:

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String filename, boolean transparency) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = MainActivity.assets.open(filename);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        if (transparency) {
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        } else {
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null,
                options);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

The image is retrieved through the assets variable which is a static variable in my MainActivity class of type AssetManager. I initialize this variable by stating assets = getassets(). My image is inside my assets folder which the AssetManager then retrieves.

Comment: How you are creating and loading the bitmap? What color density it have? What type of file it stored?

Comment: when RGB_565 it possible never have 120, 60 values

Comment: what would be a better option?

Comment: Either make bitmap always ARGB_8888, or check that r g b components not to exactly match, but Math.abs(Color.red(pixel) - 120) <= epsilon, where epsilon is at least 2 for green, and 4 for red an blue

Comment: If I have to then I'll use ARGB_8888 but I want to stray away from it for memory reasons. Is there no other config I can use? What's the default config if I don't set one?

Answer (score 0):

I am doing pretty the same in one of my app and getPixel() works perfectly.
I guess the problem is when you use Bitmap.Config.RGB_565.

In this format each pixel has not 1 byte(8 bits) per each color channel (red, green, blue). But it provides 5 bit(0-31) for RED, 6 bit(0-63) for GREEN, and 5 bit for BLUE.

So when you put pixels from PNG to RGB_565 bitmap they will be scaled from 256 possible values per each color channel to 32 values for RED and BLUE channels and to 64 values for GREEN.

Note that this transformation is not linear. It means that you can not just divide RED value from PNG by 8 and get RGB_565's RED value.